# Sylus not compiling on Azure, works locally

Tags: node.js, azure, express, stylus

I have a nodejs app that works fine locally on a windows and mac client, but when I deploy to azure is not creating the css file from stylus. Below is the relevant section from the app configuration file. Below that is the dependencies section of the package.json file.

What am I doing wrong?

```
app.configure(function() {
app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/site/img/favicon.ico'))
    app.set('port', 3109);
    app.locals.pretty = true;
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.use(assets({
        src: __dirname + '/site'
    }));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(application_root, 'site')));
    app.use(stylus.middleware({ src: __dirname + '/site/css', compile: compile}));

    app.use(allowCrossDomain);
});

"dependencies": {
  "express": "~3.1.0",
  "path": "~0.4.9",
  "stylus": "0.31.0",
  "jade": "0.27.7",
  "connect-assets": "git://github.com/asrail/connect-assets#de0d2acc935",
  "moment": "1.7.2",
  "emailjs": "0.3.3",
  "mongoose": "~3.5.7",
  "mongodb": "1.2.x",
  "markdown": "~0.4.0",
  "formidable": "latest",
  "knox": "latest",
  "node-ini": "latest",
  "node-uuid": "latest"
},
```